# how to reset the icon back after clear?

Tags: java

I have question regarding to my java project. SO I need to clear the label and text when user click the clearjmenu item. However, after click it, it does clear the label and jtextarea, but the problem is that when user re-click the number label then it suppose to setIcon again ,but it does not set any icon after clear. Is there anyway I can fix this problem?

(So basically my project is lottery game. If I press 1-9 number labels then the label image should go to chosen digit label. However if I do clear then the chosen digit label should be empty and no image. However, after doing clear, if I press 1-9 number label again then it should go to chosen digit label. The problem is that it works until clear, but after I clear then I press the 1-9 number label it does not work and image is not showing anymore.)

```
private void jLabel8MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {   
updateGuessNumber("Capture2.JPG","2");
}

private void ClearJMenuitemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {   
jTextArea4.setText("");
Icon icon = null;
jLabel13.setIcon(icon);
jLabel12.setIcon(icon);
jLabel14.setIcon(icon);
}   
   public void updateGuessNumber(String imageFile, String number)
  {
      counter++;
      switch (counter)
      {
          case 1:
              jLabel13.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Images/" +imageFile)));
              break;
          case 2:
              jLabel12.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Images/" +imageFile)));
              break;
           case 3:
              jLabel14.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Images/" +imageFile)));
              break;
           default:
          break;}

      if (counter <= 3)
          numberAsString += number;


  }
```

Comment: @Joe Jeong Please provide more details

Comment: Hi, Hasindu! I just updated updateGuessNumber method. So basically my project is lottery game. If I press 1-9 number labels then the label image should go to chosen digit label. However if I do clear then the chosen digit label should be empty and no image. However, after doing clear, if I press  1-9 number label again then it should go to chosen digit label. The problem is that it works until clear, but after I clear then I press the 1-9 number label it does not work and image is not showing anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your source code is you are using int values with case statements inside the switch while your updateGuessNumber method parameter number is a String .

So I think since it's a number **change the to method updateGuessNumber(String imageFile, int number) 
or 
change your case statements to

case "1": , case:"2" like this.**